# CSS First Child when 7 or more children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So I have this query to get the `last-child` when there are 7 or more elements

```
li:nth-last-child(7) ~ li:last-child {
    background: red;
}
```

This works for any number of elements as long as there is a minimum of `7`. What I want to do is the opposite, get the `first-child`.

I tried the following

```
li:nth-last-child(7) ~ li:first-child {
    background: red;
}
```

But that does not work. Strangely I can get the second child element using the following

```
li:nth-last-child(7) ~ li:nth-child(2) {
    background: red;
}
```

I know this is pretty complex CSS, and may not even be possible, but I am wondering if it can be done. I'd rather not use JS if at all possible. I guess treat this as a challenge ;)

Comment: *Strangely I can get the second child element using the following* Can you create a demo of it?

Comment: @ManojKumar this question has now been answered with an accepted answer. Appreciate your time to comment though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can select the first element when there are 7 or more elements by using the below selector:

```
div:first-child:nth-last-child(n+7) {
  color: red;
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `nth-last-child(n+7)` - Will select all but the last seven child elements. When there are less than seven children, this will match none.
- `:first-child:nth-last-child(n+7)` - Will select only the element which is also the first child among the elements which match the other part (which is, select only first child when there are seven or more children)

```css
.container > div:first-child:nth-last-child(n+7) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h3>Has seven children</h3>
<div class='container'>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>

<h3>Has six children</h3>
<div class='container'>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>

<h3>Has nine children</h3>
<div class='container'>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7a89m0nm/) (For some reason it is not working with `n+7` in snippet)

Comment: I could kiss you, I won't, but I could. Consider this question answered. Thank you. Saves me a whole heap of hassle. I was obviously thinking way more complicated than I should've been.

Comment: @AlexMcCabe: You're welcome pal :) I love questions like these.

Answer (score -1):

for the first element you could use the first of type in your css. Example:

```
 p:first-of-type {
        background: #ff0000;
    }
```

Comment: well, please read question before giving any answer..OP did not ask how to give color to first child. and don't worry i did not give down vote..

Comment: I gave an example, the meaning of this platform isn't giving people the answers but letting them try and learn.. I was just trying to give a possible way on how it could be solved.

Comment: Unfortunately buddy this only gives me the first child in all cases.

Comment: Well i just said the thing which  you should remember but i did not give any downvote..i used to be in that phase but then i realize, when you are not 100% sure, don't try or else you will get downvotes..

Comment: Then give a class to your div and select it that way, when you do that you don't get all cases.

Comment: @ArneBanck the menu is generated, I can't easily add a class to the first one without some code jiggery. The question has now been answered, thanks for your time though.