# How do I target the last N sibling elements only when there are Y siblings in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to target the last N sibling elements when there are Y siblings?

For example I have list of items, if and **only** if there are exactly 8, 11, 14... etc sibling elements I want the last two to look different (so `8 + 3n`).

If there is any other amount of children I want them all to look the same.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564377/css-first-child-when-7-or-more-children/33564575?s=20|0.0000#33564575

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way by far is to target each of the 2 elements you want to style with its own set of pseudo-classes.

The last child, as you state, is represented by 3n+8 (8, 11, 14...). It then follows that the penultimate child is 3n+7 (7, 10, 13...).

```css
li:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(3n+8),
li:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(3n+7) {
  color: red;
}

ul { counter-reset: item; list-style-type: none; }
li { display: inline; padding: 0.25em; }
li::before { content: counter(item); counter-increment: item; }
```

```html
<ul><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
<ul><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
<ul><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
<ul><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
<ul><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
<ul><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
<ul><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
```

You can also do this with one complex selector using the technique from [Can CSS detect the number of children an element has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has/12198561#12198561), substituting 3n+8 for the `:nth-last-child()` argument, and using an additional `:nth-last-child(-n+2)` to target the last two elements with one pseudo-class:

```css
li:first-child:nth-last-child(3n+8) ~ li:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  color: red;
}

ul { counter-reset: item; list-style-type: none; }
li { display: inline; padding: 0.25em; }
li::before { content: counter(item); counter-increment: item; }
```

```html
<ul><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
<ul><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
<ul><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
<ul><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
<ul><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
<ul><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
<ul><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ul>
```

Comment: Hello, I don't normally do this but my question has had 4 views in the 3 hours since it was posted. Would you be able to help with [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063887/black-background-in-full-screen-with-embedded-sketchfab)?

Comment: @Dan: I don't think I can, sorry. I've never used Sketchfab, and I'm not all that familiar with iframes.

Answer (score 3):

Based on

> If and only if there are 8 elements I want the last two to look different.

You'll get this:

```css
li:nth-child(7):nth-last-child(2),
li:nth-child(8):nth-last-child(1) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
Will colorize 7 and 8
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
Will colorize nothing since it has more then 8 elements
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Any way to do the second part of my question with pure CSS? Or will I need to repeat this for every variable of siblings?

Comment: Updated my question to cover all cases.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to target the last N sibling elements when there are Y
>   siblings?

Yes, you can chain pseudo-classes so that they have to match a count from the beginning *and* a count from the end:

```
ol li:nth-of-type(3n + 8):nth-last-of-type(1),
ol li:nth-of-type(3n + 7):nth-last-of-type(2) {
color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

**Example:**

```css
ol {
float:left;
width:80px;
}

ol li:nth-of-type(3n + 8):nth-last-of-type(1),
ol li:nth-of-type(3n + 7):nth-last-of-type(2) {
color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
</ol>

<ol>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
<li>Element</li>
</ol>
```