# css select last four if the last element is multiple of four, if multiple of 3 the last 3

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following css to get the last four

```
:nth-last-child(-n+4){border-bottom: none;}
```

and it returns me this result :

[image]

In this, all the last four children don't have the border bottom

but, if the last item is multiple of 3, it comes to the previously row.

[image]

What I need is:

1. when the last item is multiple of 3, select only the last 3[image]
2. when the last item is multiple of 2, select only the last 2[image]

Also, this needs to be in pure css. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take some pretty convoluted selectors not unlike the ones found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063475/how-do-i-target-the-last-n-sibling-elements-only-when-there-are-y-siblings-in-cs/35064216#35064216), but it can be done:

```
:first-child:nth-last-child(4n) ~ :nth-last-child(-n+4),
:first-child:nth-last-child(4n+3) ~ :nth-last-child(-n+3),
:first-child:nth-last-child(4n+2) ~ :nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using border bottom,

i think you should change to border top, it's suitable in your case.

Comment: No it's not - if the bottom borders were changed to top borders, there would be no bottom borders for the second last row of elements that don't have any elements underneath them.